# How can we get order details from Amazon payment Gateway?

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-s3

```
NOTE: UPDATED MY QUESTION
```

I have downloaded sample code "`Callback Sample Code - PHP`" from below url,

https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/helpTab/Checkout-by-Amazon/Technical-Resources/Code-Samples-for-Working-with-Your-Cart-and-Orders

I set the `call back url` in settings page.

As for now,I ran the sample code using zend and redirect to amazon page and clicked the button "`Place the Order`".Once order got placed it redirects to the page i gave in callback url settings.

`My Questions` is ,
In my project, i have stored all cart details in DB then passed all  to amazon. Finally i placed the order as i said above. Here i need to maintain/manage the `placed order`
Once order placed how can we get `order processed status` from call back url ? 
Any other best way to do so? Hope you understand my requirement.

Kindly advice on this.